# "Invalid conversion" error in getline

Tags: c++, getline

in this one program I'm trying to read a third line of text from a file and then take only its ending after the last space. When I'm using the getline function however it gives me a

> idp_handler.cc:37: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char’ (line 37 is the line of the first getline)

Here goes my code

```
void idp_handler::resume() {
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (PATH_R);

    string read;
    getline (myfile, read);
    getline (myfile, read);
    getline (myfile, read);

    for(int i = read.size()-1; read[i]==' '; i--) read = read.substr(i,read.size()-i);
    cout << "karp" << read << "karp" << endl;

}
```

PATH_R is just a path leading to the file I'm reading from.

Comment: So give us a clue, which line is line 37?

Comment: What's `PATH_R`? Which line is 37?

Comment: Also, you're reading, you should be using an `ifstream`, not an `ofstream`.

Comment: @user1829518 If the problem is solver, you should accept or post an answer

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `std::ifstream`, and always prefix with `std::` instead of importing `std` namespace to the global one to avoid collisions :

```
void idp_handler::resume() {
    std::ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open (PATH_R);

    std::string read;
    std::getline (myfile, read);
    std::getline (myfile, read);
    std::getline (myfile, read);

    <...>
}
```